# how to detect facebook incoming messages in javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

we are going to develop Firefox add-on like Facebook chat history.i think it's possible to detect incoming message .i have seen lot of HTTPS headers like

```
https://www.facebook.com/ajax/mercury/send_messages.php
```

i guess income chat messages also  come to browser like this.i want to know how to detect incoming facebook chat messages .i want to give alert about  incoming message content ,sender .
   i can inject javascript because it's a add-on.

Comment: Might be worth looking at signal-r (http://signalr.net/)

Comment: @Hasini Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: no response from author.. Bad practice, bad, bad.